# Sampling variance of edge density of subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, expected-value, variance, sampling, random-graphs

I would like to evaluate the mean and variance of the edge density for subgraphs obtained by repeatedly subsampling nodes.

Specifically, suppose we have an undirected graph $G$ with $N$ vertices and adjacency matrix $y$. We obtain a subset of nodes $S$ by [Bernoulli sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_sampling), i.e., for each node $i$ in $G$, we sample an inclusion indicator $z_i\sim\mathsf{Bernoulli}(\rho)$ and add $i$ to $S$ if $z_i=1$. $\rho$ is the probability for a given node to be included in the subgraph, and $n=\sum_{i=1}^N z_i$ is the number of nodes of the subgraph. Then the edge density of the subgraph $G'$ is
$$
\lambda=\frac{z^\intercal y z}{n(n-1)},
$$
where $z^\intercal$ denotes the transpose of $z$. Following [Strand (1979)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2683226), we let $\lambda=0$ for $n<2$. What are the mean and variance of $\lambda$ under the sampling scheme?

## Background Reading

[Frank (1977)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4615675) (I couldn't find an open access link, unfortunately) derives the sampling variance for an estimator of the total number of edges in the original graph defined as
$$\begin{aligned}
\hat T&=\rho^{-2}\sum_{(i,j)\in S^2} y_{ij}\\
&=\frac{z^\intercal y z}{\rho^2}
\end{aligned}$$
which is *almost* what I want. However, in the definition of $\lambda$, I divide by $n\sim\mathsf{Binomial}(N, \rho)$ rather than $\mathbb{E}[n]=\rho N$. If $N$ is sufficiently large and $\rho$ is moderate, this doesn't make much of a difference, but I have both small $N$ and $\rho$ close to 1.

[Strand (1979)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2683226) derives the expectation and variance for a simple sample mean under Bernoulli sampling. I.e., they consider the mean and variance of
$$
\bar x = \frac{z^\intercal x}{\sum_{i=1}^nz_i},
$$
where $x$ is a vector of attributes for each node. This is, again, almost what I want. But the cross terms of $z^\intercal$ and $z$ in the definition of $\lambda$ mean that I can't use the expressions directly.

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: If you divide by $n(n-1)$ rather than by an expected value, you should first decide what you want to happen if $n=0$ or $n=1$.

Comment: Good point, updated to say $\lambda=0$ for $n<2$ following [Strand (1979)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2683226).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial answer that only addresses the mean.

We can interpret $\lambda = \frac{z^{\mathsf T}yz}{n(n-1)}$ as the sum of sort-of-indicator variables $\lambda_{ij}$, for every $ij \in E(G)$, where
$$\lambda_{ij} = \begin{cases}\frac2{k(k-1)} & \text{if $i$, $j$, and $k-2$ other nodes are sampled} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Then $\lambda_{ij} = \frac2{k(k-1)}$ with probability $\binom{N-2}{k-2} \rho^k (1-\rho)^{N-k}$, so its expected value is
$$
\mathbb E[\lambda_{ij}] = \sum_{k=2}^N \frac2{k(k-1)} \binom{N-2}{k-2} \rho^k (1-\rho)^{N-k}.
$$
Using the identity $\binom Nk = \frac{N(N-1)}{k(k-1)}\binom{N-2}{k-2}$, we can rewrite this as
$$
\mathbb E[\lambda_{ij}] = \frac2{N(N-1)} \sum_{k=2}^N \binom Nk \rho^k (1-\rho)^{N-k} = \frac2{N(N-1)}\Pr[n \ge 2].
$$
Altogether, we get $\mathbb E[\lambda] = \frac{|E(G)|}{\binom N2} \Pr[n\ge 2]$, which is combinatorially nice: it's the edge density of $G$, multiplied by the probability that $\lambda$ has a sensible denominator.